# App engine - Python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Tags: json, python-2.7, google-app-engine, flask, unicode

I am doing a little Flask server in App Engine (Google Cloud Platform) with python version 2.7 and I have a problem with letters with accent marks and 'ñ' letter. I share my code here:

```
@app.route('/faq', methods=['GET'])
def get_faq():
    response = _get_faq() 
    return json.dumps(response), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

def _get_faq():
   db = MySQLdb.connect(host=CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_HOST, user=CLOUDSQL_USER, passwd=CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD, use_unicode=True, charset='utf8')
   query = "SELECT question, answer FROM faq_table"
   cursor = db.cursor(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
   cursor.execute(query)
   result=cursor.fetchall()

   faq_response = []
   for row in result:
       faq_response.append(
           {
               "question": row["question"], 
               "answer": row["answer"]
           }
       )
   return faq_response
```

But when I upload this code to App Engine and this service is called, server sends code 500 with next message in Error Reporting:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 22: invalid continuation byte

I can not resolve this problem like this:

```
json.dumps(response).encode('utf-8')
```

Always I have the same response. The trace is next:

> at iterencode (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/ec315266546cb44c/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py:270)
>
> at encode (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/ec315266546cb44c/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py:207)
>
> at dumps (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/ec315266546cb44c/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py:244)
>
> at get_faq
> (/base/data/home/apps/xxxxx/yyyyyyyy:nnnnnnn.mmmmmmm/main.py:7)

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: You have a double return in the snippet posted: is that from the actual code or copy-paste error?

Comment: 1) If it's your *server* that sends error messages, then it's your service that cannot **de**code the re**quest**. Why are you showing us the code that **en**codes the re**sponse**? 2) I don't understand why this method calls itself recursively?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Thanks for your view, i have just changed!

Comment: @AndreyTyukin 1.- My service not catch exceptions for sends to user because it makes that Error Reporting in GCP does not show anything.
2.- The method was a bad hand writting from me. 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
json.dumps(response.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks @GAEfan for your response!